# Exception from Tracker recompute function ( Invariant Violation )

Tags: reactjs, meteor, meteor-accounts

Weird behavior that I can't explain:
Here's a react component that shows a stringified object - data from google account.
[image]
[image]

If I change **`props.user[0].services`** to
                      **`props.user[0].services.google`** property
[image]
I get an **error**:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be that the services property is loaded after the function call.

The way I would solve this is using lodash to get default properties when there are none. It also prevents reference errors:

```
const googleProps = _.get(props, 'user[0].services.google', {
    picture: 'https://some-source/default-picture.png',
    email: 'unknown'
});
```